# connecting with database on ios

Tags: ios

I am facing problems to connect my applications to my database sqlite3.

How to connect with database?

Actually I want to take a name from database when I click a button.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you explain what you've tried already and exactly what kinds of problems/errors you're encountering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really use Core Data rather than trying to directly use a sqlite database. Core Data, though somewhat complex, is still much much simpler than going any other route. Apple provides numerous Core Data sample code which will help to get you started. Specifically look at the LocateMe code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this tutorial. Looks pretty nice and clear.

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Also, this wrapper for sqlite is good too.

http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/06/new_home_for_fmdb.html

Hope it helps!